# Retrieve what video resolutions(quality) a youtube video with youtube api?

Tags: .net, youtube, youtube-api

A youtube video is usually with multiple video resolutions (quality) like 240p, 360p,720p,etc how can I retrieve what video resolutions(quality) a youtube video has are there any youtube api which can get this information?Google.Apis.YouTube.v3 Client Library does not give information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we look at the doc of [YouTuve API V3](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos?hl=fr) for videos

> contentDetails.definition     
> Indicates whether the video is
>   available in high definition (HD) or only in standard definition.
>
> Valid values for this property are: hd sd

If you try in the [google Api Explorer](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/youtube/v3/youtube.videos.list?part=contentDetails&id=S8b1zWOgOKA&_h=15&) with a video of hight resolution you can see the result :

```
  "contentDetails": {
    "duration": "PT3M26S",
    "dimension": "2d",
    "definition": "hd",
    "caption": "false",
    "licensedContent": true
   }
```

`definition": "hd"`

You can't have highest resolution of the video, you can only know if it(s HD or not.
You cannot make difference between 720p, 1080p, 1440p, 2160p.

Comment: Thank you martial but I am using api for.net and believe me there is nothing like "contentDetails" in it.

Comment: @Euphoria you kidding me. `youtubeService.Channels.List("contentDetails");`  I have this feeling you want i write the code for you... I think i answered to your question, don't you think ? you never mention `.NET` i'm right ?

Comment: Thank you very very much martial for interest.Of Course I do not want code from you :).Yea it is my mistake I did not write for .NET.